# Is there a relation between factors in FA method?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, factor-analysis, principal-components

I am doing a factor analysis on my data set (I have 85 attributes and data available for 20 participants), I have decide to use 19 attributes to cover 98 % of the variation, but my result with 19 factors made me a bit confused.
I have plot the factors diagram by using the function `fa.diagram` and I have noticed that there are exist some relation between my factors and I do not understand it.

Here is a picture of my factors:

[image: picture of my factors]

And here is the code I am using:

```
fa<- fa(scaled,nfactors=19,rotate="promax",fm="pa" , symmetric =TRUE)
fa.diagram(fa, simple = FALSE)
```

Can you explain me the meaning of these loads ( ex : between PA14 and PA10 it has a load equal to 0.3 )?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (SO)! It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to solve your problem. You can have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: Is there a significance to the factors not being listed in chronological order in the excel sheet and pdf? If yes, what?